# Response from one page to another page in php without ajax

Tags: php

I am just started with Php and have some doubts.

I created 2 pages one.php and two.php

```
ONE.php
<body>
  <form method="post" action="TWO.php">
    First Number<input type="text" name="txt1"><br>
    Second Number<input type="text" name="txt2"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

TWO.php
<body>
  <?php
    $sum=$_POST["txt1"] + $_POST["txt2"];
    echo $sum;
  ?>
</body>
```

I POST values form one.php to two.php. Two.php calculates the sum and echo's the result.
My query is would I be able to get the sum echoed on one.php using just php and its important to post the data on another page and get the response from there.

Comment: redirect to one.php page with sum param and get sum in one.php.

Comment: Without AJAX you will have page reload. Do you agree it?

Comment: @jQuery: great it is a solution but sir what if the data is not just the sum and some large data which should not be reveled.

Comment: @Alejandro: Its ok to reload.

Comment: @Sumeet . then you need to use php session. store date in session before redirect to one.php page. if session is set print that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are. Simply, handle the form submission (the POST request) in *one.php*. When the request for *one.php* is not POST just show the form.

The typical way is:

```
// ONE.php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $content = "Sum is " . $_POST["txt1"] + $_POST["txt2"];
}
else {
    $content = <<<EOC
     <form method="post" action="ONE.php">
        First Number<input type="text" name="txt1"><br>
        Second Number<input type="text" name="txt2"><br>
        <input type="submit">
     </form>
EOC;
}
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ONE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- or whatever charset you are using -->
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $content ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edited, the OP needs the two files but print the result on *one.php***

In order to pass data between two files you can:

- Set the data in the first file (*two.php*) and require the second (*one.php*, where you would print the value)
- Use [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

With the latter you need to do a (well you don't *need to* but it's mean to work with a) page redirect, so my recommended approach for this case is use the former. The code could be something like:

```
// TWO.php
<?php
// you should probably check if $_POST['txt1'] and $_POST['txt2'] does really exists and throw and error if not...
$sum = $_POST["txt1"] + $_POST["txt2"];

require "ONE.php" // careful if you're on a *nix file system the NameCase is extremely important!


// ONE.php
<?php
if (isset($sum)) {
    $content = "Sum is " . $sum;
}
else {
    $content = <<<EOC
     <form method="post" action="TWO.php">
        First Number<input type="text" name="txt1"><br>
        Second Number<input type="text" name="txt2"><br>
        <input type="submit">
     </form>
EOC;
}
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ONE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- or whatever charset you are using -->
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo $content ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolutely sir, I very much appreciate your efforts but its important to post the data on another page and get the response from there.

Comment: @Sumeet, how about now?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<body>
<?php
if($_POST){
    $sum = $_POST["txt1"] + $_POST["txt2"];
    echo $sum;
}else{
?>
<form method="post" action="">
        First Number<input type="text" name="txt1"><br />
        Second Number<input type="text" name="txt2"><br />
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this, in only one page:

ONE.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="ONE.php">
        First Number<input type="text" name="txt1"><br>
        Second Number<input type="text" name="txt2"><br>
       <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        // Verify if $_POST["txt1"] and $_POST["txt1"] are defined
        // (when form is submit $_POST, $_GET and other $_ PHP vars 
        // are set). If form isn't submitted, set 0 on each variable 
        // to perform sum. Is necessary check values to avoid PHP
        // Warnings/Errors (In this case with isset function. There
        // are many different ways to perform it)
        $txt1 = isset($_POST["txt1"]) ? $_POST["txt1"] : 0;
        $txt2 = isset($_POST["txt2"]) ? $_POST["txt2"] : 0;
        $sum = $txt1 + $txt2;
        //Print sum result
        echo 'Sum is: '.$sum;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

For comparations I'm using [ternary operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981723/how-to-write-a-php-ternary-operator), that simplify/minimize code of traditional if/else. Also [you can use traditional if/else (simple compare) or switch(multiple compare)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104767/php-if-else-statement)