# PHP find out student record using functions

Tags: php, mysql

- Table: **student**
  [image]
- student.php

  ```
  <?php
  function findStudentRecord()
  {
        //Db connection

        $q1 = "select * from student where gender = 'F'";
        $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);
        $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($r1);

        $record = array();
        if($total_records > 0)
        {
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($r1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $record[] = $row1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //[HERE]
        }

        return $record;
  }

  $record = findStudentRecord();
  //[HERE]
  ?>
  ```
- I want to find female student record but there is no record from my database. How do I return 0 value from function and display "No record found" on my web page in [HERE] section?

Comment: ´return 0;´ and then use a if sentence to determine the record? or, `return "No record found";`

Comment: use if statement to return "No return found"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP if/else statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104767/php-if-else-statement)

Answer (score 2):

```
if($total_records > 0)
```

add no else block so it will return an empty array now you can do something like this

```
$records = findStudentRecord();
if(count($records) === 0) {
    echo "No record found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not change your function. It returns an array (may be empty) in any case wich is quite consistent.

Instead look at the number of array items returned:

```
$record = findStudentRecord();
//[HERE]
if(count($record) == 0) {
  echo "No record found";
} else {
  // what ever
}
```